# Bicommerce API create product sku

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to create product sku using bicommerce api. I'm getting 'invalid options' error or empty response.

In bigcommerce api documentation, then mentions options parameter should be object like following.

`This is an object {"product_option_id": int, "option_value_id":int}`

But, I tried by converting this parameter to object too. Below my code.

```
$url = $store_url . '/products/110/skus';
$skus['sku'] = '814922018828-FR';
$optionObj['product_option_id'] = 20;
$optionObj['option_value_id'] = 74; 
$skus['options'] = $optionObj;
$xml_response = $this->cUrlResponsePost($url, $username, $api_key, $skus);
```